# Перевод SPA на React с помощью Symfony

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony

кто может объяснить мне алгоритм перевода SPA на React? На бэке использую Symfony.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPA - это всего лишь методология разработки приложения,которая говорит, что приложение будет одностраничным, весь контент будет менять фронтовый движок (React/Vue/хоть чистый js), твой вопрос не совсем точный, что ты имеешь в виду говоря о переходе со SPA на React?

Comment: Извините, некорректно поставил вопрос, я имел ввиду интернационализацию сайта на разные языки.

Comment: Даже так :)

Могу предложить такой вариант решения:
Использовать библиотеку [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/), она довольно простая, весь перевод хранится в **json** формате, который вы можете формировать на **Symfony**, тут уже все зависит от требований к задаче.

Если ответ вам помог, то пометьте ответ как "`Полезен`", спасибо :)